# GMAP.NET left drag, hide overlap, and more

Tags: gmap.net

I have GMAP.Net.Windows version 1.93 by Jurgen De Leon Rodriquez.  Does anyone know if this is the best version to use?  If not, what is a better version? 
 I'm having some issues and I was wondering if perhaps I have a "less than par" version.

For instance, I want the left mouse button to be able to drag the map.  When I use this code:

```
myMap.DragButton = MouseButton.Left
```

All it does is disable the right button for dragging, but does not enable the left button.

I was also trying to create a toggle for an overlay, but my code produces an error:

```
myMap.Overlays("markers").IsVisibile = False
```

The error is:  System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "markers" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out.

For Overlays, I had to set a variable as an overlay and set that.  I would think I wouldn't HAVE to, but it's how I got it to work.

```
myMap.Overlays.Add(ScheduledOverlay)
ScheduledOverlay.IsVisibile = True
```

As for the Mouse button, this was simple to:

```
myMap.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left
```

It's MouseButtons not Mousebutton.  Not sure why there are two...